# rails jquery tokeninput returns "not a function"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-tokeninput

I'm trying to integrate tokeninput in my little rails app following Ryan Bates Railscast nbr 258.

Therefore,

I added the tokeninput files in the vendors directory

I then changes my application.js file:

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.tokeninput
//= require bootstrap
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker.min
//= require_tree .
```

Then I added this code in the file categories.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#company_category_list').tokenInput('/categories.json',
    theme: 'facebook'
    prePopulate: $('#company_category_list').data('load')
  )
```

When I go to my form, the browser console says:

```
TypeError: $(...).tokenInput is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

prePopulate: $('#company_category_list').data('load')
```

I've been looking for a couple of hours but I don't find the cause of this error. The jquery.tokeninput files seems to be loaded correctly by the asset pipeline.

Any help, suggestion welcome!

Comment: Sorry i can't helo, but i'm having the same problem

Comment: I could solve it yesterday evening. Jquery was loading twice because of Rails precompiled assets. Maybe you can check double loading of jquery...

Comment: Thanks, I solved it that way as well.

Comment: Hello, can you please explain how you fixed this? What did you do to prevent jquery from loading twice?

Comment: It's explained in the second comment above

Comment: I'm precompiling my assets as well. What did you specifically do to fix the issue? Did you disable precompiling the assets? This won't work for me because I need to precompile assets for my Heroku app

Comment: Yes, I don't precompile in dev anymore, and I deleted precompiled assets from my public folder. You can set Heroku to precompile automatically everytime you push. Actually Heroku does it by default.

Comment: @ndemoreau - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize:

The issue I had was due to the fact that I once precompiled my assets and then decided to compile on the fly:

- It's not handy for debugging in dev mode
- Heroku manages precompilation automatically when pushing the code

The precompilation created minified version of the assets in my public folder.

When I run my website, all the javascript files were then loaded twice: Once from the public folder and once from the normal flow.

I just deleted what I had in my public folder and it solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks for following up! I can't delete my answer since it has been accepted, but I've up-voted yours, and added a comment to mine to ensure that your elaboration is seen by any who need this answer.